# Usage of Homicide

Tags: word-usage

**Homicide** (n) means, *the **act** of killing another person*

Is it ok to say, "You homicide" or the action verb **do** must be used, "You do homicide"?

**Example:**
When you smoke, you homicide (you kill passive smokers)

Comment: "You homicide" is trying to use homicide as a verb and as you have noted  homicide is a noun.

Comment: @MaxW Ah, but don't they say that in English, every noun can be verbed?

Comment: Another way you could approach this is to use the adjective "homicidal." As in, "Smoking isn't just suicidal—it's homicidal." A homicidal act is one that is likely to result in homicide, and a homicidal person is one who intends to commit homicide.

Comment: Maybe every noun *can* be verbed, but not every noun *is* commonly verbed, and I would expect this particular one to cause confusion, at least in the suggested sentences.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**[Homicide](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/homicide)** is a **noun**. The verb that goes with "homicide" is usually [**commit**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/commit). One can commit homicide, commit murder, commit a crime, etc. "Do" is a poor choice because it is too general.

"Homicide" is not used as a verb, so "to homicide someone" is not correct.